# Webpack alias issue

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

I have a little problem with one webpack setup and I'm here hoping someone had the same issue and came with a solution.

## Issue

I'm trying to use alias inside HTML/SCSS/JS files.

At the moment it works only fully in SCSS files, partially in HTML files and not at all in JS files.

So for example this works:

```
<img src="~images/slogan.png" alt="" width="324" height="211">
```

but in style tag it doesn't:

```
<div class="hero__image" style="background-image: url(~images/slogan.jpg)"></div>
```

It doesn't throw any errors it just outputs as it is - with the alias string.

## Code

**webpack.config.js**

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
            'assets': utils.srcPath(),
            'vendor': utils.srcPath('vendor'),
            'images': utils.srcPath('images'),
            'fonts': utils.srcPath('fonts'),
            'scss': utils.srcPath('scss'),
    }
  },
```

style rule:

```
{
    test: /\.(scss|css)$/,
    use: [
        {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
                publicPath: '../../',
                sourceMap: true,
                hmr: isDev,
                reloadAll: true
            },
        },
        {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: true
            }
        },
        'resolve-url-loader',
        {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                plugins: [
                    require('autoprefixer')({})
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
                sourceMap: true,
                sassOptions: {
                    importer: globImporter()
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

html rule:

```
{
    test: /\.html$/,
  loader: 'html-loader',
  include: utils.srcPartialsPath(),
  options: {
    interpolate: true
  }
}
```

## What information I dig up

The only information that I was able to dig up was for the order of `'resolve-url-loader'` and to change it, but without any success. Adding it before the `css-loader` breaks the setup, adding it before the `sass-loader` does nothing.

Other than that nothing else that can point me to the issue at hand.

## Summary

Alias is working for img `src` attributes but not for inline CSS.

Any insight will be much appreciated!